# Fail glue job through code(i.e. Manually)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue

I want to fail the glue job, through code. 
Is there any approach through which we can do it, in python.

Comment: write an incorrect code that you know will fail.

Comment: Without looking at any docs or APIs - have you tried setting a non-zero exit code? Like `exit(-1)` that's usually the way to tell that something failed or should fail.

Answer (score 3):

```
raise Exception("{}:Exception raised: {}".format(job_name, err))
```

It will throw error and failed glue job.